# What are the mechanisms that allow you to do a cantrip as a bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, homebrew, warlock

I'm digging around the players handbook, and so far all I see is the eldritch knight ability, and thats not quite what I need.

I'm trying to bring hideous blow over from 3.x to 5e for warlocks, but make it not suck. I was thinking maybe I could just sidestep the issue and make a mechanism that allows you to just cast eldritch blast as a bonus action when making an attack, maybe through an item or invocation? I'd rather not make it an invocation, but if I did I'd make it require the crossbow expert feat and some other crap.

Are there any magic item or class features I missed that allow you to cantrip as a bonus action?

Comment: It's not really clear what you end goal is here.  What specific effect are you trying to port over?  Are you just looking for a way to make Eldritch Blast a melee attack?  If so, is there a reason that just reflavoring the existing Eldritch Blast to be a melee attack?  Spellcasting no longer provokes attacks, so such a reflavor might get you what you want, without messing with mechanics at all.  It would be helpful to say exactly what you want to keep from Hideous Blow, and what you want to leave behind.

Comment: I'm confused as well. Do you want to create a melee-ranged *eldritch blast* or the ability to cast a cantrip as a bonus action?

Answer (score 9):

The only mechanism that allows a character to cast cantrips as a bonus action is the Sorcerer's Quicken Spell metamagic ability.

The Eldritch Knight, in particular has no such ability - they have an ability that lets them make a weapon attack as a bonus action.